# Can user client change auth state using browser console?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have initialised my credentials and auth on the client. Are they are able to go into console and change their authentication or is firebase secure enough that it requires users to actually signup/login? I don't want a user to easily login through console, I want them to sign up rather than finding a loophole. Below is code in the client js file that they see.

```js
await firebase.initializeApp({
        apiKey: DATA,
        authDomain: DATA,
        databaseURL: DATA,
        projectId: DATA,
        storageBucket: DATA,
        messagingSenderId: DATA,
        appId: DATA,
        measurementId: DATA
});
auth = firebase.auth();
```

Answer (score 0):

A user can do whatever they want in the console of the browser. So in your client-side code you should always assume that the data you see may be false/spoofed.

However, the user can't spoof the [security rules of your database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security). The `auth` variable in the rules is guaranteed to be the actual Firebase Authentication data for the user that called `auth.signIn...`.

Specifically: there is no way for a user to claim the UID of another user in security rules by making calls to the client-side authentication SDK.